# Events from multiple forms on one page in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, forms, meteor

In my home.html page, I have two forms, which have been set up in the same way. The problem is one works and the other doesn't. I tried putting on of the checkboxes from the broken form into the working form, and it starting working, so I think it's an issue with specifying the form in the JavaScript Template.events code.

html:

```
<template name="home">
<form> <strong>Display Factors:</strong><br> 
          <label class="display-F1"> <input type="checkbox" checked="{{displayF1}}"> 1: Cumplimiento de los objetivos del programa </label><br>
          <label class="display-F2"> <input type="checkbox" checked="{{displayF2}}"> 2: Estudiantes </label><br>
          <label class="display-F3"> <input type="checkbox" checked="{{displayF3}}"> 3: Profesores </label><br>
          </form>

          <form>
          <label class="display-strengths"> <input type="checkbox" checked="{{displayStrengths}}"> Display Strengths </label>
          <label class="display-insuff"> <input type="checkbox" checked="{{displayInsuff}}"> Display Insufficiencies </label>
          <label class="display-urgencies"> <input type="checkbox" checked="{{displayUrgencies}}"> Display Urgencies </label>
          </form>
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```
Template.home.events({
"change .display-strengths input": function (event) {
  Session.set("displayStrengths", event.target.checked);
},
"change .display-insuff input": function (event) {
  Session.set("displayInsuff", event.target.checked);
},
"change .display-urgencies input": function (event) {
  Session.set("displayUrgencies", event.target.checked);
},
"change .display-F1 input": function (event){
    Session.set("displayF1", event.target.checked);
},
"change .display-F2 input": function(event){
    Session.set("displayF2", event.target.checked);
},
"change .display-F3 input": function(event){
    Session.set("displayF3", event.target.checked);
},
});
```

I have other code relying on Session.get, but I'm fairly confident the problem is in this code because, in the console, `Session.get('displayStrengths')` returns true when appropriate, but `Session.get('displayF1')` always returns undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem isn't with the code you provided. Check out the demo I made with the code you provided:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/rm56RY49Gq7yyfa6D/Leaderboard

If you run it (with the chrome/firefox/whatever console on) and click on each of the selections, you should see the correct corresponding message "I got called X". You can also type in `Session.keys` directly into the console and you should see the expected results.

Comment: I also tested the code on a local installation and everything seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Still not sure why it wasn't working in the first place, but moving one form and it's event handlers into a separate template worked. Thanks for the help